# Easiest way to convert an HTML into WordPress system

Tags: php, css, html, wordpress

I made an HTML 5 web-template, but I know nothing of PHP, [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET), etc. I love how WordPress works, but still no PHP. How can I integrate things into my template? Would it make much trouble?

Comment: try to learn PHP .its really useful . if you dont want for first just make change in a wp template for months than you might be able to convert Html to Wp

Comment: Heres a nice free program that I use to convert my html sites to wordpress on http://www.wpsiteconvertor.com/. It's very simple and gets the job done real quick. Comes with some usefull options like jquery check, woo commerce compatability and unlimited sidebars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to separate your template into multiple files (header.php, footer.php, single.php, page.php, etc.) to turn your template into a WordPress theme. You have to first understand how WordPress works. For this, you can start [here](http://thethemefoundry.com/blog/html-wordpress/).

I was in the same situation as you two weeks ago. I understand how things work and now I own a theme (very simple, but functional).

Answer (score 2):

You will have to learn just a bit of how PHP works if you want to integrate your template in WordPress. WordPress uses PHP to render the page. To be simple, PHP loads the template and create the render for the browser with the values needed (like the title the posts, comments). So you have to understand how it works before to modify your HTML5 template.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should learn the basics of PHP first of all, and should have basic knowledge of WordPress. There is a theme of WordPress:

http://wordpress.org/themes/blankslate‎

You can download this and convert this into your WordPress theme... just by replacing your HTML and CSS parts... But it has some code in PHP, so play with it with special care. You can get more information in *[How to create a WordPress theme?](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/wordpress_create_theme.htm)*.

Comment: The first link is broken.